# Format Date in moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

How to get "Yesterday/Today/Tomorrow/NextWeek" as ouput on passing date as a string in moment.js.

```
  var date = "12/11/2015";
```

After passing this to ***moment***, need output whether the date is

`Yesterday` or `Today` or `Tomorrow` or `NextWeek` .

Comment: where is your effort?

Comment: Effort is below. I solved my own query and posted so that others having same issue can save time.

Answer (score 3):

```
formatDateAsDay("12/11/2015", "DD/MM/YYYY");

formatDateAsDay(date,format) {
  var dayName = window.moment(new Date(date)).calendar(null, {
    lastDay:'[Yesterday]',
    sameDay: '[Today]',
    nextDay: '[Tomorrow]',
    nextWeek: 'ddd',
    sameElse: format
  });

  return dayName;
}
```

In moment there is a calendar function that takes callback object which we can format based on our requirement.